# php how to split url from string

Tags: php

how to split this url ?

```
https://example.in?url=https://test.in/admin/qrcode.php?s=qr&d=sps_dev_chanel_3&sf=8&ms=r&md=0.8&format=text
```

i need string after url, like below

```
https://test.in/admin/qrcode.php?s=qr&d=sps_dev_chanel_3&sf=8&ms=r&md=0.8&format=text
```

Comment: `parse_url()` will extract the URL parts. But your example is invalid, because the "url" parameter contains an URL which is not urlencoded (it is mandatory to encode special characters in parameters)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = "https://example.in?url=https://test.in/admin/qrcode.php?s=qr&d=sps_dev_chanel_3&sf=8&ms=r&md=0.8&format=text";

echo $string;

$urls = explode("url=",$string,2); // explode with limit 2

var_dump($urls); 

echo $urls[1]; // this is your result
```

[image: Preview]